# cannot do 2nd level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, ehcache

### in my applicationcontext.xml

```
<bean id="annotatedsessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="packagesToScan" value="testonly.package.model" />
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
        </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
<property name="dataSource">
    <ref bean="dataSource" />
</property>
```

### In my Entity

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)

@Table(name = "TestPOJOCATEGORY")
@NamedQueries({
 @NamedQuery(name = "TestPOJOcategory.findAll", query = "SELECT h FROM TestPOJOcategory h"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "TestPOJOcategory.findById", query = "SELECT h FROM TestPOJOcategory h WHERE h.id = :id"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "TestPOJOcategory.findByCategoryname", query = "SELECT h FROM TestPOJOcategory h WHERE h.categoryname = :categoryname")})
public class TestPOJOcategory implements Serializable {
```

### In My Dao

```
public List<TestPOJOcategory> getAllCategory(final String keyword, final int nFirst,
        final int nPageSize,
        final String sortColumnId,
        final boolean bSortOrder) {

  List<TestPOJOcategory> result = (List<TestPOJOcategory>) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session) {
      Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(TestPOJOcategory.class, "TestPOJOcategory")
       .add(Restrictions.ilike("categoryname", keyword))
       .addOrder(bSortOrder ? Order.asc(sortColumnId) : Order.desc(sortColumnId))
       .setFirstResult(nFirst).setMaxResults(nPageSize);
      System.out.println("why still call from DB? suppose to call from cache");
      return crit.list();
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

### echcache.xml

```
 <cache name="testonly.package.model.TestPOJOcategory"
        maxElementsInMemory="200"
        eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="300"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    />
```

Each time I call the dao, it will still call from DB. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your `System.out.println()` statement will get executed every time whether or not 2nd level cache is accessed because such access takes place within `list()` method.

Secondly, Criteria - much like Query - does **not** automatically use 2nd level cache; configuration properties you've specified merely **enable** it to be used. You still need to explicitly mark each Query / Criteria instance as cacheable by calling [`setCacheable(true)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setCacheable(boolean)):

```
Criteria crit = ...;
crit.setCacheable(true);
return crit.list();
```

On a side note, since you're using `HibernateTemplate` you might as well use it right :-) and get rid of manual `doInHibernate` wrapper:

```
public List<TestPOJOcategory> getAllCategory(final String keyword, final int nFirst,
    final int nPageSize,
    final String sortColumnId,
    final boolean bSortOrder) {

  DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TestPOJOcategory.class);
  crit.add(Restrictions.ilike("categoryname", keyword))
   .addOrder(bSortOrder ? Order.asc(sortColumnId) : Order.desc(sortColumnId));
  getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(true); // works on both queries and criteria
  return (List<TestPOJOcategory>) getHibernateTemplate()
   .findByCriteria(crit, nFirst, nPageSize);
}
```

Comment: may i know where should i put system.out.print to check the method is calling from db or cache?

Comment: here is what i do to check whether the query if from db or cache.  use show_sql to check.

Comment: show_sql is correct; and you already have it in your configuration. If the SQL is not printed that means query results are retrieved from cache.

Comment: for 2nd level cache and query cache. is it a required to create entity statement like above in ehcache.xml? i commented out the line and it still work

Comment: It's not **required** to have `ehcache.xml` at all - defaults will work. It's usually **good** to have it as you can specify settings more appropriate to your situations, though. Query / criteria caches use separate cache regions so they won't use settings you've specified above for entity. Check Hibernate / ehcache documentation for details on cache region names / configuration.

Comment: for the above getAllCategory(..) before I return the List I need to do getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(false) right?  because only this cache query need to be cached.

Comment: Yes, you need to set it back to false before you invoke the query you don't want cached.

Comment: Great answer!  Helped me today to a solve similar nagging problem!

Answer (score 5):

Well, using the second level cache doesn't mean that you can find an object in the cache based on any arbitrary HQL (or Criteria) query. The second cache is only used when accessing the object by its key or when navigating an object graph.

So, here, you'll need to use **query caching** (yes, there are 3 caches: the first level cache, the second level cache and the query cache). This needs:

```
session.createQuery("query").setCacheable(true);
```

Or, when using `Criteria`:

```
session.createCriteria(...).add(...).setCacheable(true);
```

And hibernate properties set (which you have):

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
```

Actually, I'd warmly suggest to check the following resources if you want to get a better understanding of the various caching mechanism Hibernate uses and of what Hibernate caches exactly (i.e. "dehydrated" entities):

- [Hibernate: Truly Understanding the Second-Level and Query Caches](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)
- [Speed Up Your Hibernate Applications with Second-Level Caching](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/29685/0)
- [Hibernate Caches](http://acupof.blogspot.com/2008/01/background-hibernate-comes-with-three.html)

The two first articles are a bit old but still apply. The later is more recent. All are good readings IMO.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the references. i already read those before posting

Comment: +1, good links. I haven't seen the last one before, very nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a SQL statement gets executed, then turn on the show_sql property on (or the org.hibernate.SQL logger).

Otherwise, Hibernate caching is mainly by primary key. This makes is very useful when an object needs to be refreshed or many-to-one relationships are traversed. Keeping a cached result set for an arbitrary query consistent through random concurrent updates/inserts/deletes that may or may not impact the result set seems very complicated. Unless you have a performance problem I wouldn't recommend caching queries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have missed configuring the cache on the hibernate level.  It looks like you need to add the following to your hibernate configuration file to enable caching.

```
<cache usage=”read-only” />
```

You also may want to check this link out, it looks pretty good.
http://blog.dynatrace.com/2009/03/24/understanding-caching-in-hibernate-part-three-the-second-level-cache/

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I'm using annotated class not hbm.xml. do i need to addd that line? where?